# Java client server communication

Tags: java, server, client

I am trying to make a java program for client-server communication

- I need to initialize a server socket and a client socket.
- The server socket will accept a connection from the client.
- After the connection has been accepted, the input i give to the client will be submitted to the server which will tell the client if the communication was successfull or not.

This is my code :

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.net.*;

  public class ClientServer {

  public static void main(Strings args[]) throws Exceptions{
  /*initialize server socket*/
  Socket client_socket = new Socket("localhost", 12345);
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client_socket.getInputStream()));
  BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client_socket.getOutputStream()));
  String serverMsg = null;
  while ((serverMsg = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println("Client: " + serverMsg);


  ServerSocket server_socket;
  server_socket=new ServerSocket(12345);
  while (true) {
  Socket mysocket=server_socket.accept();

  BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(mysocket.getOutputStream()));
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mysocket.getInputStream()));
  writer.write("prova\n");

  System.out.printls("data sent");
  }
  }
  }
```

but I need to get input from keyboard, not "from the code".

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you should have 2 classes, 1 for the server and 1 for the client.... and the use scanner or similar to get the user input from the console....

Comment: Yeah, i know i sound use 2 classes like most exaples i found do... but I mean...  I specifically got told to use only one... So i made a Class ClientServer and i instatiated 2 sockets in it...